# How to line up duplicated values on same row?

Tags: excel

for example,

```
2018        totalsale    2019        totalsale
brand a     2,000        brand b     10,000
brand b     3,000        brand d     5,000
brand c     4,000        brand a     2,500
brand e     3,000        brand f     3,000
```

desired result

```
2018        totalsale    2019        totalsale
brand a     2,000        brand a     2,500
brand b     3,000        brand b     10,000
brand c     4,000        
                         brand d     5,000
brand e     3,000
                         brand f     3,000
```

I tried to use append and merge in power query like this video suggests https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2OaYuxlm54, but the totalsale didn't follow.

Are there simpler ways to achieve this goal like excel formula and something else?
Thank you for all answers.

Comment: Would you be interested in a VBA solution?

Comment: Yes I'm interested

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're currently working on columns A, B, C and D. Create two additional columns E and F.

Column E should contain the entire list of brands. If you can't use a formula, you could paste 2018 and 2019 in a single additional row and use an advanced filter to copy the unique values. Then for column F:

```
=VLookup($E2,C:D,2,FALSE)
```

VLookup looks for the contents of the first parameter in the range specified in the second parameter (in this case columns C and D) and when found copies the contents of the second (2) column. The False toggle makes sure it doesn't approximate and only looks for exact matches.

There's a family of functions that's also helpful, namely the DB functions (such as DB.SUM). These would help you to get totals if multiple cells satisfy the VLOOKUP criterion (e.g. you'd have more totalsale cells for one brand).

Comment: Thank you I'll try that